# iOS - Getting experience details from linkedIn

Tags: ios, linkedin-api

We are developing an  IOS application  ,where we need experience details from linkedIn so that we can find complete user experience. Could anyone provide direct API's or some code.

I used this URL but i'm not getting the education and experience details

NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,email-address,picture-url,public-profile-url,education,experience)"];

Comment: first search google.... https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/ios-sdk.... this link will provide you all information...